# MongoDB Schema optimization for saving users contacts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to design a schema for storing Contacts of Users.

Here are my existing schemas:

**User Schema**

```
_id : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a77"),
name : “something”,
email : “something”,
password : “something”,
```

**Profile Schema**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a88"),
user_id - ref
mobile : “something”,
company” : “something”,
designation : “something”,
website : “something”,
social: {
    youtube: {
        type: String
    },
    twitter: {
        type: String
    },
    facebook: {
        type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
        type: String
    },
    instagram: {
        type: String
    }
}
```

I can think of two approaches to the Contact schema but both have some cons:

**First approach**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a99"),
user_id - ref,
"contacts": [
   {
    name : “something”,
    company : “something”,
    designation : “something”,
    website : “something”,
    social: { something },
    mobile : “something”
   },
   {
    name : “something”,
    company : “something”,
    designation : “something”,
    website : “something”,
    social: { something },
    mobile : “something”
    },
    ...
]
```

The problem with the above structure is that when the User updates their Profile the Contact fields can not get the updated value. But in this approach, it is easy to query and retrieve all Contacts of a particular User and send the response back.

**Second approach**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c53653451154c6da4623a99"),
user_id : ref,
contacts: [
    profile_id,
    profile_id,
    profile_id,
    profile_id,
    profile_id,
    profile_id,
    ...
]
```

In this structure Contacts have the updated User value when the User updates their Profile. But the problem here is while querying I have to fetch the profile id from the Contact schema, then query the Profile schema and return the value to the client as a response.

What happens when there are 30K-50K contacts - do I need to query the DB 50K times? Or is there a better approach?

Building on node.js, using mongoose.

Comment: will there multiple contacts of one user?

Comment: User Schema and Profile Schema should be the same.

Comment: No, it is like one user is saving contacts of another user in the contact array and so on. He can save as much as he wants.

Comment: User schema is here basically for login. Rest user have to create their own profile, and save contact (which is profile) of other users.

Comment: You should use one document for one contact and ref by userId.(Who saved it)

Comment: If you want, may I give?

Comment: I didn't get your point!

Comment: Yeah sure, if you have some sample code, then please share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have a scenario where relational database will be required. But You can also achive this in **mongo** .

You need to use **populate** of mongoose. With your second approach. Where you storing profile ids.

```
User.find({_id: '5c53653451154c6da4623a77'}).populate({
path:'profiles',
options: {
    limit: 10,
    skip: 0
}}).exec();
```

[Mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

This query will return related profiles. If you have data like 50K. You must limit the data in one request.

**NOTE: Mongodb limit for per document is 16mb. It is not possible to store that much data.**

So, Just rethink your database.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I think you've correctly identified some pros/cons of each option. Now you have to decide what makes sense for your specific case. Option 1 will be easy for fetching but tedious for updating and keeping in sync with `Profile`s. Option 2 has more normalized data and will be better for updating but will require more queries to retrieve. So you have to ask yourself some questions.

- How important is having normalized data to you?
- How will the size of your `Profile` vs `Contact` schemas compare? Will you have significantly more Profiles? Significantly less? Orders of magnitude?
- What happens more often - that someone updates their profile or that someone queries for contacts? How much more? Orders of magnitude?
- To dive deeper into your last two answers - do some estimates, even rough ones if you have to, and then do some math to see what might make more sense.

For example, if you will have 10,000 contacts per user then option #1 will give you a much larger document that can gather all contacts and profiles in a single query. If your users only update their profiles say, on average, once a month but you need to query contacts several times a day this might be the better option. However, if you have users who like to update their profile daily and you need to query contacts maybe once a week then option #2 could make more sense.

At the end of the day it's a design choice that is very specific to your scenario. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 schemas one is for the user and another for orders. One user can create multiple orders like your contacts.

user-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      trim: true,
      type: String,
      required: [true, "firstName is required!"],
      validate(value) {
        if (value.length < 2) {
          throw new Error("firstName is invalid!");
        }
      }
    },
    lastName: {
      trim: true,
      type: String,
      required: [true, "lastName is required!"],
      validate(value) {
        if (value.length < 2) {
          throw new Error("lastName is invalid!");
        }
      }
    },
    email: {
      unique: [true, "Email already registered"],
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"]
    },
    password: {
      trim: true,
      type: String,
      require: [true, "Password is required"],
      validate(value) {
        if (value.length < 6) {
          throw new Error("Password should be atleast 6 characters");
        }
      }
    },
    mobile: {
      trim: true,
      unique: [true, "Mobile Number already available"],
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Mobile Number is required"],
      validate(value) {
        if (value.length !== 10) {
          throw new Error("Mobile Number is invalid!");
        }
      }
    },
    gender: {
      trim: true,
      type: String,
      enum: [
        "Male",
        "Female"
      ],
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
    },
    dob: {
      trim: true,
      type: Date,
      required: [true, "DOB is required"],
    },
    Address: {
      address: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        require: [true, "Owner Address is required"]
      },
      city: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        require: [true, "Owner Address City is required"]
      },
      state: {
        trim: true,
        uppercase: true,
        type: String,
        require: [true, "Owner Address State is required"]
      },
      pin: {
        trim: true,
        uppercase: true,
        type: Number,
        require: [true, "Owner Address Pin is required"],
        validate(value) {
          if (!(value >= 100000 && value <= 999999)) {
            throw new Error("Pin is invalid!");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const Users = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);

module.exports = Users;
```

Order-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const orderSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    trim: true,
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
    required: [true, "User ID is required"]
  },
  dateOfOrder: {
    trim: true,
    type: Date,
    required: [true, "Date of Order is required"],
  },
  dateOfMeasurement: {
    trim: true,
    type: Date,
  },
  dateOfTrail: {
    trim: true,
    type: Date,
  },
  dateOfDelivery: {
    trim: true,
    type: Date,
  },
},


  {
    timestamps: true
  });

const Orders = mongoose.model("Orders", orderSchema);

module.exports = Orders;
```

Comment: No, it is not same as mine, though I have one question which will probably solve my problem: How are you going to fetch the Profile info of all users who placed an order? Like there are 50K users who placed the order, and you have to show their profile, all the info that is in the user schema?

Comment: Then you will have to use aggregate in mongodb

Comment: You will fetch all orders and groupby by userid and fetch users, who placed orders.

Comment: yeah, but my project is too heavy and complicated.

Comment: Okay, no problem, just clear me one thing:  so while fetching users, I have to query DB the same number of times as the count of the user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is actually why mongodb is not the best choice for this scenario. Your data is relational, but you are using a non-relational database.

---

But for your situation there are some steps to make it better:

**First approach**

You can choose the first approach and when a user data is updated, also update all contacts. Easier query but hard to keep data in sync.

**Second approach**

Or you can choose the second approach, but instead of just saving the ref_id also save the contact name (the field is mostly gonna be used for querying). this way it would be easier to keep the data in sync and if search is done by name, you could just do a normal find.